# plural changes in velocity .

Tags: grammatical-number, science

Is the plural for changes in velocity delta velocity's or deltas velocity?
Basis for confusion:attorneys general.
Each stage in a rocket has a set amount of delta velocity, or the amount the velocity can change over any amount of time. If I want to get the delta velocity for the first stage and the 3rd but not the second what plural form do I use.

Comment: Delta velocities.

For example,
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1499002

Answer (score 3):

It would be 'delta velocities'.

Nouns are pluralised — modifiers aren't. An attorney general is a type of attorney (hence 'attorneys general'), and a delta velocity is (sort of) a type of velocity, so 'delta velocities' it is.

As an aside, I've heard 'delta' used as a noun often enough that 'velocity delta' and 'velocity deltas' sounds fine to me too. I prefer 'delta velocities', I think, but depending on context something like 'changes in velocity' or 'accelerations' might be more readable.

Comment: I would actually prefer velocity deltas.  It emphasises that these are multiple measurements of change.  But +1

Comment: i agree with this one. a delta velocity isn't a type velocity. in maths delta means change. as you derive you keep measuring different changes. delta distance over a set amount of time is velocity. delta velocity over a specific time is acceleration but in rocketry the set amount of time can change drastically.